# Speed of an electromagnetic soliton in free space

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, speed-of-light, solitons

What is the speed of an electromagnetic soliton in free space? Is it equal to 'c' ?

P.S. My understanding of the Fourier transform says it's not.

Comment: What is "soliton" and "speed" for you, if EM wave equation solution is, then it is automodal to $x-ct$. If that means "moving with C", yes it is.

Comment: I mean a disturbance in the electromagnetic field which is not continuous like an electromagnetic wave. https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/physik/KSND/abb/sol1.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the speed of the soliton is $c$. You can read more about the wave equation (which governs EM waves) [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation).

Comment: I should say that I had the 1-d wave equation in mind, as you show in your gif. I am not sure what localized travelling wave solutions look like in 3d.